# Trying to get name of data stored in reader

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have datareader which reads through 5 names with different values attached to each name.
While debugging i can get to each name using this expression computed by VS:

```
(new System.Collections.Generic<System.IO.FileInfo>(((School.PackageReader)(reader))._incomingStudents)).Items[0].Name
```

This above code while debugging gives me values i need like 5 different names when i change Items from 0 to 1 or 2... But when i try to use above code in my .cs file i get errors. Is there anyway to use this in code and get the values?

Comment: You get errors... and those errors are?

Comment: What is `PackageReader`?

Comment: Error is: Namespace 'System.Collections.Generic' does not have type parameters. An PackageReader is a data reader class created to read through student records.

Comment: Please update your question with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because you did not define the type of `Collection` you wanted to use.

I assume you are looking for a `List`, in which case you need to instantiate it this way:

```
    (new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>(((School.PackageReader)(reader))._incomingStudents)).Items[0].Name
```

Though it doesn't seem like this would be a good case for a `List` as you are calling a single value in `Items[0].Name`.  BUT that's where your error is coming from.